# Core Data Entity attribute disappearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I create a `Core Data` `Entity` with Magical Record in one of my classes. I save the context and assign the `Entity` to a custom Cell object's property.

I then pass the cell object to a different class which displays it. At some random point, the `Entity`'s attributes become nil.

I can still find the `Entity` in the data base and is still valid. At no point does the cell object become de-refereance (its stored in a class property array).

So, at one point in my program, here is the `Entity`:

```
2013-05-08 13:58:51.425 DEBUG | -[DatasetSubBar doesCellArray:containCellWithDataset:] | cell.dataset: <SavedAnalysis: 0x22b0a4d0> (entity: SavedAnalysis; id: 0x22bba720 <x-coredata://42CA4347-1DF1-4C6B-AB44-03EFE3D86F3A/SavedAnalysis/p110> ; data: {
    createDate = "2013-05-08 18:58:00 +0000";
    name = "Unsaved Analysis";
})
```

a few seconds later:

```
2013-05-08 13:58:54.417  DEBUG | -[DatasetSubBar createDisplayPanelCells] | cell.dataset.name: (null)
2013-05-08 13:58:54.417  DEBUG | -[DatasetSubBar createDisplayPanelCells] | cell.dataset: <SavedAnalysis: 0x22b0a4d0> (entity: SavedAnalysis; id: 0x22bba720 <x-coredata://42CA4347-1DF1-4C6B-AB44-03EFE3D86F3A/SavedAnalysis/p110> ; data: <fault>)
```

The pointer to the Entity is still alive, but the name property is nil.

I check the database and the Entity is still there:

```
Dataset *test = [Dataset MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"imageHandle" withValue:self.testImageHandle inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]];

DLog(@"MR_contextForCurrentThread | lost dataset: %@", test);
```

.

```
2013-05-08 13:58:54.408  DEBUG | -[DatasetSubBar createDisplayPanelCells] | MR_contextForCurrentThread | lost dataset: <SavedAnalysis: 0x1e8157a0> (entity: SavedAnalysis; id: 0x22bba720 <x-coredata://42CA4347-1DF1-4C6B-AB44-03EFE3D86F3A/SavedAnalysis/p110> ; data: {
    createDate = "2013-05-08 18:58:00 +0000";
    name = "Unsaved Analysis";
})
```

I'm baffled that the `Entity`'s property would become nil while the `Entity` itself remains referenced and the entity is still in the database. I am using ARC.

Comment: I think that happens if the objects managed object context is deallocated.

Comment: I don't suppose there's a message sent when it would be deallocated so I could confirm this? I did set up a catch that if the `Entity`'s attributes become nil, to re-fetch it form the database. After a re-fetch, I don't see the issue happening again. So this looks like the solution, but would be nice to be certain.

Comment: No, but it looks as if you have a design problem. Each object is part of one particular context. If the context is deallocated, all its objects become invalid. - There is one trick how you can debug this: set a custom object as [associated object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject) of the context and set a breakpoint in the custom objects dealloc method: If the context is deallocated, the assoc. object will be deallocated as well.